# Can't seem to add simple user input to my DB via a form

Tags: php, mysql

This is very quick.

I have a form that when submitted should add user input into my DB. I have had a similar form working well but for some reason this one is not working.

Please excuse my sloppy code but here is the whole page. For some reason 'observation' will not take the user input and display it on the next page (showOne.php). The next page simply shows a blank space for observation and I checked the DB and there was nothing in the observation field of course.

Is it something simple that I can't see? I've been at this for days since it is identical to another form I have that works well on another page.

Thank you for any insight.

```
<?php
//including the database connection file
include("config.php");
$activePage = "start.php";


if(isset($_POST['update'])) {  
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $observation = $_POST['observation'];

    $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "UPDATE tasks SET observation='$observation' WHERE id=$id");

header("Location: showOne.php?id=$id");
}

//getting id from url
$id = $_GET['id'];
//selecting data associated with this particular id
$result2 = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=$id ORDER BY id ASC");
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM tasks ORDER BY taskNumber ASC");


include_once "nav.php";
?>

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Pathfinder - A User Testing Dashboard</title>
<meta name="description" content="Pathfinder - A User Testing Dashboard">
<meta name="author" content="James Stables - Thurs April 13th 2017">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="core.css">

<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600,700" rel="stylesheet">

<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script     src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.js">        </script>
<![endif]-->
```

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


</head>
<body>
<header>
<a href="index.php"><h1 class="logo"><img src="images/logo.png">Pathfinder</h1></a>
<h4>User Testing Dashboard</h4>
</header>

<section class="nonav">
<div class="showAllUsers">
<table border='0'>
    <tr>
    <?php while($res = mysqli_fetch_array($result2))
    { ?>
        <td class="widthHundred no-border left"><h2><?php echo $res['nameFirst']; ?></h2></td>
    <?php } ?>

    </tr>
</table>

<table border='0'>
<thead>
<tr>
    <th>Image</th>
    <th>Category</th>
    <th>Task Number</th>
    <th>Task Name</th>
    <th>Observation</th>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td> 
</tr>
</thead>

<tbody>

<form name="start" method="post" action="start.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

```
<tr>
    <td><a href="<?php echo $res['$image'];?>" data-lightbox="example-1" data-title="Task Number&nbsp;&nbsp;<?php echo $res['taskNumber'];?>">
    <img id="imageResize" src="<?php echo $res['image'];?>" /></a></td>
    <td><?php echo $res['category'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $res['taskNumber'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $res['taskName'];?></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="observation" value="<?php echo     $res['observation'];?>"></td>  
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>   
<?php } ?>

</tr>
<tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>        
    <td><input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $_GET['id'];?>"><input type="submit" class="buttonUpdate right" name="update" value="Update"></td>
    <td><a class="buttonCancel right" href="tasks.php" onClick="return confirm('Cancel and go back?')">Cancel</a></td>
</tr>



</form>

</tbody>
</table>

</div>

</section>

<script src="js/lightbox-plus-jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
lightbox.option({
  'resizeDuration': 200,
  'showImageNumberLabel': false,
  'fitImagesInViewport': true
})
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you considered some basic troubleshooting like outputting the observation, update, and id variables before you try to update the DB to make sure they're what you expect? You're vulnerable to SQL injection and you should probably require (instead of include) on that config file. Unless you truly want the page to try to run if the config file is missing.

Comment: Also see about using parametrised queries

Comment: Thank you @mkaatman I echoed the $observation variable and got an empty value. The $result var = 1.

Comment: @Strawberry Thank you, I'll look into that and implement it when I get the page working. I think you are right , for security reasons. Thanks